# Remove text from string after a certain repeated character

Tags: c, string

```
char str[] = "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\folder\\test.txt";
char *ptr;

ptr = strchr(str, '\\');
if (ptr != NULL) {
    *ptr = '\0';
}
```

How do I remove the last ' \ ' including test.txt so it is just "C:\Users\test\Desktop\folder"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `strrchr`

> Locate last occurrence of character in string
> Returns a pointer to the last occurrence of character in the C
> string str.
>
> The terminating null-character is considered part of the C string.
> Therefore, it can also be located to retrieve a pointer to the end of
> a string.

Also you need to escape the backslashes with `\\`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\folder\\test.txt";
    char *ptr;

    ptr = strrchr(str, '\\');
    if (ptr != NULL) {
        *ptr = '\0';
    }
    puts(str);
}
```